# How do I remove the remote URL being added to an Axios POST request?

Tags: javascript, amazon-ec2, axios

I have a React Web Application and a NodeJS Server, both deployed to Ubuntu EC2 instances. I've confirmed that API calls can be made between them using a CURL request to the private IP address (they're both in the same subnet).

However when I make the call from the React application, the POST request URL is prefixed with the remote URL which causes the API call to fail.

[image: Chrome Developer Tools]

The request URL is meant to be `http://10.11.1.147/login`

It works fine when running both applications on localhost. The API framework is implemented using Axios and React-Query.

Here is the query function performing the POST request (and I've confirmed that REACT_APP_SERVER_URL is the private IP address)

```
export const postLogin = async ({ email, password }) => {
  let response;
  const cookies = new Cookies();
  try {
    response = await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/login`, {
      email: email,
      password: password,
    });
    cookies.set("JWT", response.data.jwt, { path: "/" });
    cookies.set("UserId", response.data.userId, { path: "/" });
  } catch (err) {
    return err.response
  }
};
```